# Combining Sympy and uncertainties

Tags: python, sympy, uncertainty

I'm trying to use sympy to solve a polynomial equation, the coefficients of which have uncertainties. So for the uncertainties I'm trying to use the uncertainties module. Is there any way of doing the following:

```
x=ufloat(10,0.2)  #the xs are coefficients
x1=ufloat(8,0.01)
x3=ufloat(25,2)
L=Symbol("L")
eqn=(x*(L**2))+(x1*(L*1))+(x3*(L**0))
solve(eqn,L) #ideally this should give the value of L with it's propagated uncertainty
```

without it throwing the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Variable' and 'Pow'
```

Comment: Did you mean to not use `x1` and `x3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use `Symbol('x')` and then substitute it for your ufloat (you'll probably need to use `lambdify` to do this). This should work, assuming that SymPy is able to solve the equation in the general form with the symbolic coefficient. Since this is just a quadratic, it will. For a cubic it would too, but for higher order polynomials, you are out of luck. I'm also assuming that `ufloat` will do the right thing when plugged into the quadratic equation.

Something like

```
x, x1, x3 = symbols('x x1 x3')
L=Symbol("L")
eqn=(x*(L**2))+(x1*(L*1))+(x3*(L**0))
s = solve(eqn,L)
lambdify([x, x1, x3], s)(ufloat(10,0.2), ufloat(8,0.01), ufloat(25,2))
```

(note there are two solutions to the quadratic, so this will give both).

Comment: A quartic should work too, except for https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=4003.

Comment: I've been trying this with no luck. Could you perhaps be more explicit? I have no experience with lamdify and reading the documentation wasn't very enlightening.

Answer (score 2):

There is a python package based on uncertainties and sympy which does it: [maabara](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/maabara)

It is still in beta, but see examples [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/dudheit314/9333733/maabara-tutorial.ipynb)

---

**update**

The links above are already invalid. You may find the package on [github](https://github.com/dudheit/maabara).
Here's the [User Guide](https://github.com/dudheit/maabara/blob/master/docs/user_guide.rst)

---

**update Mar 2 2019**

The links above are dead too.
You may find a package of the same name on [github](https://github.com/c2man/maabara).
Here's the [User Guide](https://github.com/c2man/maabara/blob/master/docs/user_guide.rst)

Comment: @Graipher  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Graipher I find a package of the same name, but not sure if it's still useful...